# Boolean algebra's filter as a partially order's filter

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, filters

This is a basic question I'm trying to figure out: why the Boolean's filter definition corresponds to the order-theoretic definition of filter ?

Here follows the relevant definitions.

> **Definition 1** (Filter in a partially ordered-set)
> A nonempty subset $F$ of a partially ordered-set $(P, \le)$ is a *filter* on $P$ if the
> following conditions hold:
>
> 1. $F$ is **downward directed**: for every $x, y \in F, \exists z \in F$
>    *s.t.* $z \le x$ and $z \le y$.
> 2. $F$ is **upward-closed**: for every $x \in F$ and $y \in P$, if $x \le y$ then $y \in F$.

> **Definition 2** (Filter in a Boolean algebra)
> A nonempty subset $F$ of a Boolean algebra $(\mathbb{B}, \vee, \wedge, \bot, \top, \neg)$ is a
> *filter* if it is
>
> 1. **downward directed**: $\forall x, y \in F, x \wedge y \in F$;
> 2. **upward-closed**: $\forall x \in F, y \in \mathbb{B}, x \vee y \in F$.

Boolean algebra seen as a lattice can be presented with a relation order $\le$ with the following equivalence:
$$x \le y \iff x \vee y = y \iff x \wedge y = x.$$

My question is, under a Boolean algebra, why the two definitions of filter aforementioned are equivalent ?

It's pretty clear to me that the property of upward closure is equivalent as $x \vee y = \sup\{x, y\}$. But I have doubt about the first property (downward directed), especially the direction (Definition 1 $\implies$ Definition 2). For the reverse direction, we can take $z = x \wedge y$.

**Draft**:

$z \le x \textrm{ and } z \le y \iff z = z \wedge x \textrm{ and } z = z \wedge y$, and by substitution we have $z = z \land (x \land y)$. How can I prove that $z = x \land y$ and thus by hypothesis $x \land y \in F$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we're working with a definition 1 filter.

Let's let $x,y \in F$. We want to show $x \land y \in F$.

By definition 1, we know there's some $z \in F$ with $z \leq x$ and $z \leq y$.
Then by the definition of $\land$, we must have $z \leq x \land y$ too.
Lastly, by upwards closure, we see $x \land y \in F$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: It does, thanks!